# Do any Australian banks allow PayWave/PayPass over $100?

Tags: credit-card, australia

I use PayPass regularly on my MasterCard. I knew there was a $100 limit on contactless transactions, but I always thought you could go above that - and you'd just have to enter your PIN to authorise it.

Well, I got caught out the other day when I had a contactless-only card with me (it sticks on the back of my phone, no chip and not swipable) and tried to make a $130 transaction. That's when I discovered that $100 limit is a hard limit after all!

As far as I can tell from looking at a couple of bank sites, these limits appear to be set by the bank rather than the payment network.

Are there any Australian banks (or credit unions or any other card issuer) who have a higher contactless limit, with or without PIN required?

Comment: I have both CBA and ANZ Visa cards and both have a limit without pin of $100 but with pin I have purchased over $300 with both of them.

Comment: @Victor Just to clarify, that's with contactless? I'm with CBA as well...

Comment: Yes with paypass, it may depend on the card type, my CBA card is a Gold Visa.

Comment: I have a CBA Diamond card and have never been able to Paywave above $100 without a pin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes.**

Long answer:

Yes, A lot of the leading banks in Austalia (think NAB, Commonwealth Bank, etc) offer much higher spend limits on contactless, although with most banks, any contactless transaction over $100 requires a PIN to be entered.